# Trying to make terminal alias

Tags: terminal, alias

I'm trying to create an alias in my .bash_profile to run an application in the terminal window (Julia programming language), the same way you would run Python from the terminal window by typing "python".

I created a .bash_profile and put

```
alias julia="path"
```

But it says 'No such file or directory', and in fact I tested it out with directories that I know exist, and no matter what I put there, when I type the command in the terminal it still says it.  Can anyone troubleshoot this for me?

Thanks.

Comment: Need more info. Where is Julia installed? Also, why create an alias rather then just add `julia` to your $PATH. (Also, while this is subjective these days, aliases would more traditionally go in .bashrc. This has no effect on your issue though).

Comment: @sdmeyers Julia is installed in my Applications folder, how would I add julia to my $PATH?

Comment: `PATH="${PATH}":/Application/Julia-0.3.0.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/` Assuming the latest binary release.

Comment: BTW if you generally use `julia` from the command line, I'd suggest installing homebrew (http://brew.sh) and then `brew install julia`.

Comment: above path... `Application` s/b `Applications`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question:

```
alias julia="/Applications/Julia-0.3.0.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia"
```

tested.

(You need to make sure the alias goes inside the OS X app package all the way to binary.)